# Create ES6 Class Methods from other class methods

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, currying, es6-class

So I have a class with a curried method

```
class myClass {
  constructor () {}

  curry (a,b) {
    return (a,b) => {}
  }

}
```

Now can create another method with the curry? Something like this

```
class myClass {
  constructor () {}

  curry (a,b) {
    return (a,b) => {}
  }

  newMethod = curry()
}
```

Comment: I don't believe "currying" is the correct term for that. "A method that returns a function" would be more precise.

Comment: @JLRishe I think he means currying, which is functional programming. In ES6 Class the instance is always returned, so I think the answer on his question is "no".

Comment: @JLRishe I can create a method that returns a function, my question is "can I create a method from the method that returns a function?"

Comment: You can add any function as method to an object. Not sure what this question is about.

Comment: @NielsSteenbeek [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) is a mechanism that allows breaking down a function call into a series of one-argument calls. OP's example takes two arguments so this is not currying. I think this question would probably be better if OP skipped the fancy terminology and explained their requirement in clear language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can easily do that - just put it in the constructor:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.newMethod = this.curriedMethod('a') // partial application
  }

  curriedMethod(a) {
    return (b) => {
      console.log(a,b);
    }
  }
}

let x = new MyClass();
x.newMethod('b')
```

Comment: There is an issue here. The curried function is inside a class property now, it's not a true method. The difference is that a method does exist before the class is initialized. While for most cases this sounds like nitpicking, things change if you need to do static analytics on the class. (for example, angular AOT compiling)

Comment: @SanderElias Depending on which call uses the `this` keyword, you can also use a `const makeMethod = (a) => function(b) { console.log(a, b, this); };` with  `MyClass.prototype.newMethod1 = makeMethod(1); MyClass.prototype.newMethod2 = makeMethod(2);` to get real class methods